# XPath - Get row/cell with no specified child

Tags: html, xpath

I have HTML like that:

```
 <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="LOCK">
       <img src="lock.img" alt="Row locked">
    </td>
    <td class="ID">
    </td>
    <td class="LOCK">
    </td>
    <td class="ID">
    </td>
</tbody>
```

I would like to create xpath which select for me first  which is unlocked.
Only locked ID has xpath `.//td/img.`

I created something like that:
`.//td[not(img)]/following-sibling::td[@class,'ID']`
But it's not working...
I am able to find td via xpath `.//td[not(img)]`, but when I add condition for ID, then I see all td, no matters if is with `img` or not.
Maybe there is a simple solution which I could not find.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

To get all `td` elements having no `img` child elements you can use this XPath:

```
//td[not(.//img)]
```

BTW, your XML here is invalid.
It should be something like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="LOCK">
       <img src="lock.img" alt="Row locked"></img>
    </td>
    <td class="ID">
    </td>
    <td class="LOCK">
    </td>
    <td class="ID">
    </td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly your xml could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="LOCK">
      <img src="lock.img" alt="Row locked"/>
      I should NOT be found
    </td>
    <td class="ID">I should NOT be found</td>
    <td class="LOCK">I should NOT be found</td>
    <td class="ID">I should be found</td>
    <td class="LOCK">I should NOT be found</td>
    <td class="ID">I should be found</td>
    <td class="LOCK">
      <img src="lock.img" alt="Row locked"/>
      I should NOT be found
    </td>
    <td class="ID">I should NOT be found</td>
    <td class="LOCK">I should NOT be found</td>
    <td class="ID">I should be found</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

`.//td[not(img)]` selects also the td with @class='ID' .

To only select the td with @class='LOCK' use `.//td[@class='LOCK'][not(img)]`

`following-sibling::td[@class,'ID']` selects all the following siblings with  @class='ID'.

To get only the first add an extra `[1]` to tell to only to use the first.
(It is the shorthand for `[position()=1]`)

The XPath would then be:

```
.//td[@class='LOCK'][not(img)]/following-sibling::td[@class='ID'][1]
```

This will select the rows with the text 'I should be found'

Comment: Does this answers your question?